# How to best use multicolumn index with value ranges in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I'm running SQL Server 2016 Enterprise edition.

I have a table with 24 columns and 10 indexes. Those indexes are vendor defined so I cannot change them. I have a hard time to understand how to get best performance as whatever I do SQL Server chooses in my opinion a poor execution plan.

The following query :

```
SELECT event_id
FROM Events e WITH(NOLOCK, index=[Event_By_PU_And_TimeStamp])
WHERE e.timestamp > '2022-05-12 15:00' 
  AND e.PU_Id BETWEEN 103 AND 186
```

results in this index seek:

[image]

The specified index is the clustered index and it has two columns `PU_ID` and `Timestamp`. Even though the SEEK PREDICATE lists both `PU_ID` and `Timestamp` as the used columns the "Number of rows read" is too high in my opinion. Without the index hint SQL chooses a different index for the seek with double rows-read number.

Unfortunately the order of the columns in the index is `PU_ID, Timestamp`, while Timestamp is the much more selective column here.

However if I change the PU_ID condition to list every possible number between the margins

```
PU_ID IN (103,104,105,...186)
```

then the "rows read are exactly the number of returned rows" and the statistics output confirms a better performance (validated with profiler trace).

Between-condition:

> (632 rows affected)
> Table 'Events'. Scan count 7, logical reads 139002, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 1, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

IN-condition with every number written out:

> (632 rows affected)
> Table 'Events'. Scan count 84, logical reads 459, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Edit: the IndexSeek for the IN-query
[image]

What is the best way to make SQL Server choose the better plan?

Do I really need to write out all possible PU_IDs in every query?

The used index is just a simple two column index, it's just the clustered index as well:

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [Event_By_PU_And_TimeStamp] ON [dbo].[Events]
(
  [PU_Id] ASC,
  [TimeStamp] ASC
)
```

Comment: Is this a parameterized query e.g. in Entity framework or a stored procedure? If it is then could be parameter sniffing, try with `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` To see if anything looks better.10 index is quite a lot to choose from. Also wonder if you change between to > 103 and < 186 as I know there are issues with between with dates! Ideally would be good to see each index if that is the full example above

Comment: Please attach the plan for the IN Query

Comment: You can't use an multi-column seek index for multiple range predicates, it's just impossible. With `IN` the compiler will split it into multiple separate seeks (up to a limit) so it works out as: seek `PU_Id` forward-scan `timestamp`. Yes, writing out each one may be quicker, but it may not be, especially if there are a lot. A join against a table variable of IDs (with a primary key of course) may be faster still

Comment: @PabloHenkowski - added the seek details for the IN-query

Comment: @Andrew - thanks, currently it is just plain SQL with hardcoded values, so no, it's not parameter sniffing. And yes, between and > and < does not make any difference here. Tried that already.

Comment: You should try the BETWEEN query with the MAXDOP query hint: OPTION(MAXDOP 1)

Comment: @Charlieface - thanks, this sounds like it could be the right explanation. I think I need to discuss with the vendor if they could add a one-column index on time here as time is the most selective column on the table.

Comment: @PabloHenkowski - thanks, the parallelism cost seems to be low, nevertheless I tried the maxdop, but also with maxdop the result in the number of rows read is the same 6million

Comment: "I have a table with 24 columns and 10 indexes." - you likely have too many indexes. "Those indexes are vendor defined so I cannot change them." - talk to your vendor. I often see vendors with minimal DB chops. Also: stop using NOLOCK!

Comment: @MitchWheat - I agree that there are too many indexes - 3 of them have 0 seeks, 0 scans, 0 lookups and a whole lot of updates. Another 3 of them have only a few thousand seeks but the same multi million updates which in my eyes make them also obsolete - but our vendor is hard on the indexes : support = standard setup. NOLOCK is fantastic :) - we are using production database for reporting, any locks affect production. We plan to get a db replica for reporting, then it might become obsolete.

Comment: you do realise that NOLOCK can return incorrect data?

Comment: @MitchWheat - yes, but our production data is a one-way-street - data coming in and never changeging. Production events are captured and saved, they will never be deleted or updated, so for us the priority is to not impact performance by report queries.

Comment: "data coming in and never changeging" - in which case you don't need NOLOCK. Readers don't block readers (even if you are not in RCSI)